# Render index of duplicate elements at table using JFace

Tags: java, eclipse, jface

I have been trying to render table using jface.
the issue is one of the columns I render holds the index of the element inside the array.
I do the follwoing:

```
TableViewerColumn tableViewerColumn = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
tableViewerColumn.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {      
    public String getText(Object object) {
        //EmployeeNames is list of String
        return String.valueOf(company.getEmployeeNames().indexOf(object)+ 1);
    }
});
```

This will always return first index occurance in case there are any dublicates.
I don't have the luxury to alter the type of the EmployeeNames.

Can you give me a hint to handle this index issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1: Index of cell

Here a small class that can be used as a column label provider to show the row number in a JFace TableViewer.

Basically it does not look for the index of the object associated to the cell, but for the cell itself.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.CellLabelProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerCell;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerColumn;

public class RowNumberLabelProvider extends CellLabelProvider {

    private TableViewer viewer;

    protected void initialize(ColumnViewer viewer, ViewerColumn column) {
        super.initialize(viewer, column);
        this.viewer = null;
        if (viewer instanceof TableViewer) {
            this.viewer = (TableViewer) viewer;
        }
    }

    public void update(ViewerCell cell) {
        super.update(cell);
        if (viewer != null) {
            int index = Arrays.asList(viewer.getTable().getItems()).indexOf(cell.getItem());
            cell.setText("" + (index + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

To use it, simply set it as the label provider of your column

```
TableViewerColumn tableViewerColumn = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
tableViewerColumn.setLabelProvider(new RowNumberLabelProvider());
```

I'm not sure if it will work also when there are filters enabled or the table is sorted.

---

### Solution 2: Search by reference

As an alternative you could also try to look for the object by reference:

```
 TableViewerColumn tableViewerColumn = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
 tableViewerColumn.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {

     public String getText(Object object) {
         int index = 1;
         for (String employee : company.getEmployeeNames()) {
             if (employee == object) 
                 return String.valueOf(index);
             index++;
         }
         return "";
     }
});
```